# Is it possible to test the "else" part of my apex method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Here is the code of my method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getCity() {
    User currentUser = [SELECT City FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND City != ''];
    if(currentUser.City != ''){
        return currentUser.City;
    } else {
        Default_city__mdt defaultCity = [SELECT City__c FROM Default_city__mdt Limit 1];
        return defaultCity.City__c;
    }    
}
```

And this is the code of my test method, which covers only part of the method:

```
@isTest static void testGetCityCurrentUser(){
    String city = WebServiceLWC.getCity();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, city, 'city value is null');
}
```

How do I cover the rest of my method? After all, the value of `'City'` always remains filled in and I will not get into the `else` part of the method in any way...

Comment: Your `else` is unreachable because the SOQL query that returns `currentUser` already filters based on `City`. The only way to hit that else branch is to modify the code. You could use dependency injection to change the source of `currentUser`, but that seems like a lot of work to cover two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can throw a "No rows returned" QueryException, because you're filtering to see if the city is not blank/null. Instead, consider code like this:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getCity() {
    for(User currentUser: [SELECT City FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND City != null]) {
        return currentUser.City;
    }
    return [SELECT City__c FROM Default_city__mdt Limit 1].City__c;
}
```

Now, in order to test both paths, update your city:

```
@isTest static void testGetCityCurrentUser(){
    update new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId(),City='Somewhere');
    String city = WebServiceLWC.getCity();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, city, 'city should not be null');
    update new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId(),City=null);
    city = WebServiceLWC.getCity();
    System.assertEquals(null, city, 'city should be null');
}
```

Note that I set City to ensure that it is not null before attempting to call your test. This prevents "random" failures depending on who runs the code.